# Template argument deduction fails

Tags: ros, subscribe, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have this call for a Subscriber:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = handle.subscribe<std_msgs::Bool>(topic_str.str(), 10, boost::bind(obIcCb, _1, i));
```

Why do I need to specify the type for the `subscribe` call?

If I remove the type specification so that the call is:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = handle.subscribe(topic_str.str(), 10, boost::bind(obIcCb, _1, i));
```

Then I get a big error message that says `no matching function for call` and many instances of `template argument deduction/substitution failed` like this:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(std::basic_stringstream<char>::__string_type, int, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void>
>, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<unsigned char> > >)’
    ros::Subscriber sub = handle.subscribe(topic_str.str(), 10, boost::bind(obIcCb, _1, i));

template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/sterlingm/ros_workspace/src/ramp/ramp_planner/src/main_obstacle_twist_all.cpp:357:90: note:   mismatched types ‘void (T::*)(M)’ and ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> >, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<unsigned char> > >’
    ros::Subscriber sub = handle.subscribe(topic_str.str(), 10, boost::bind(obIcCb, _1, i));
```

When I put the type back in, it compiles. Can someone help explain why I have to specify the type in this call to `subscribe`? My callback function is **not** a class member. It's signature looks like this:

```
void obIcCb(const std_msgs::Bool data, const int index)
```

Edit: Very minor edit, just wanted to make it clear that the name in the function signature above matches the name I'm using in my subscribe call.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233525/template-argument-deduction-fails/) by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 380 on 2016-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [Functor Objects section](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Functor_Objects) in "roscpp/Overview/Publishers and Subscribers" wiki:

> Note: when using functor objects (like `boost::bind`, for example) you must explicitly specify the message type as a template argument, because the compiler cannot deduce it in this case.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2017-10-03**:
That must be the issue. Thanks for this follow up.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if this is the problem, but usually my callbacks take a ConstPtr type, e.g.,

```
void imageCallback (const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& img)
```

Also the callable can be a functor or function pointer.

Maybe for these reasons type deduction isn't possible in general.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2016-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2016-05-04**:
That was an issue with my code I saw after making this post, but it doesn't fix the template problem.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2016-05-09**:
My understanding is, that there is no "template problem". You need to state the type of the ros message because it is not deducible by the compiler.

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2016-05-09**:
This is not always true though. One can see in the ROS tutorials that the `subscribe` call compiles without specifying the type: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node